# Create separate menus with footer and header with wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create two separate menus on my page for header and footer. I created two separate menus. However, I used the following function to add the `<i></i>` tag inside the `<a></a>` tag to wp_nav_menu for the footer.
However, while this function worked for the footer, it broke my header menu.

The function I added

```
function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
   return preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="footer-menu-link"', $ulclass);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','add_menuclass');
```

If I describe my problem with a picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMik7.png)

I don't want to delete this function. Because this time the footer menu is broken. Can't I send this function as a variable in the menu name? I want this function to work only for the footer menu.

Or how else can I do that, I'm also open to dysfunctional solutions

My English may be bad, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forcing a class onto the a tag with a function you could target it using CSS.

And then target the a tag with:

```css
footer nav a {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<footer class="global-footer wp-block-group has-text-color has-white-color has-background has-blueberry-1-background-color wp-block-wporg-global-footer">
  <div class="wp-block-group global-footer__navigation-container is-layout-flow wp-block-group-is-layout-flow">
    <nav class="global-footer__navigation-important wp-block-navigation is-layout-flex wp-block-navigation-is-layout-flex" aria-label="">
      <ul class="wp-block-navigation__container  global-footer__navigation-important wp-block-navigation">
        <li class=" wp-block-navigation-item wp-block-navigation-link">
          <a class="wp-block-navigation-item__content" href="https://wordpress.org/about/">
            <span class="wp-block-navigation-item__label">About</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: Yes it's a nice idea, but I tried it didn't work. It worked when I tried this with the online editor[link](https://codepen.io/burhanakts/pen/BaGXrEK)


What is the logic of not working on a website?

Comment: I see, you are trying to change the list icon or use the double chevron before the item. I've done this by adding the icon into the Wordpress menu item by changing the Navigation Label to include a Font Awesome icon code. Your bootstrap icon might also work. Or this solution for changing the list icon might also work: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-decorate-list-bullets-in-arrow-using-css/